# Search form is shown differently when using AJAX vs standard

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

When I use the bootstrap search form like this, I get this output (as I wanted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Show", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-search" })) {
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="search" class="span2 search-query" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

[image]

However, when I want to turn this into a ajax form, I'm receiving this output:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "contentlist"
    })) {
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="search" class="span2 search-query" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

[image]

Why does the type of form make a difference? The generated HTML is the same in both cases.

Edit: solved, I'm a dumbass.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the generated HTML is the same? Bootstrap does that when there's *something* between the appended controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no class name for the ajax form. You should add `class = "form-search"`.

Comment: Well, that solved it. Totally overlooked that and I missed the `class` tag in between the several data tags. Will accept answer in a few minutes.